# Help Understanding Predicate Logic Statement: "A jolly clown is a tyrant."

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm having some trouble working through the translation of the statement "A jolly clown is a tyrant.
The book says "this is ambiguous, and to give two rival translations." I don't quite understand why though.

(Using: Jx : x is jolly, Cx : x is a clown, Tx : x is a tyrant).

My first intuition was to go with something like:

$
(\exists x)[(Jx \wedge Cx)\wedge (Tx)]
$

*(There exists a jolly clown that is a tyrant).*

However the portion that says it ambiguous makes me think there is something I'm missing, and that it might be more akin to a conditional... like:

$
(\forall x)[(Cx \wedge Jx) \rightarrow (Tx)]
$

*(If a clown is jolly then they are a tyant).*

Can anyone help me out by letting me know if I'm on the right track? Or provide some advice to my method?

Comment: The second one. "A jolly..." means a jolly whatever.

Comment: I think you are on the right track. "A jolly clown..." in English may be interpreted as "One jolly clown ..." or "Any jolly clown...", which exactly corresponds to the two sentences you are giving,

Comment: Thank you, I found a section in another text that describes more in detail the ambiguity between a "universally quantified conditional" and a "existentially quantified conjunction" dealing with statements like "A (blank) is (blank)."